# If a mapping is continuous and a bijection, the inverse mapping is also continous?

Tags: general-topology

On my textbook, I was given the following conditions for when a continuous mapping is a homeomorphism:

"Let(X,τ) and (Y,τ′) be topological spaces and f a function from X into Y. Then f is a homeomorphism if and only if
(i)f is continuous,
(ii)f is one-to-one and onto; that is, the inverse function f^−1:Y→X exists, and
(iii)f^−1 is continuous"

I was wondering whether the third criteria is even needed. If a mapping satisfies the first two, shouldn't the inverse mapping automatically be continuous?

Comment: Consider the identity map from $\mathbb R$ with discetre topology to $\mathbb R$ with usual topology. [BTW this question has been asked many times on MSE].

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . Even if $(Y,\tau')=(X,\tau),$ a continuous bijection $f:X\to X$ can fail to have a continuous inverse.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Of course. But that requires a non-trivial construction and I wanted to given an immediately verifiable example.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I guess i was thinking too much about standard functions in calculus